tmux and vim require an initial sleep
I wonder if someone can help me solve the following puzzle.
I have a script which runs tmux with vim, and splits the window left/right. The problem is that vim doesn't render properly. Only half the text is rendered, and the text that's displayed does not match where the cursor is. Generally it's just a corrupted vim display. I have a kludged a solution, which I don't understand, and which I'll explain further down. But first the script:
#!/bin/sh

tmux new-session -d "vi lorem.txt"
tmux split-window -h
tmux select-pane -t 0
tmux attach-session

The file lorem.txt is 5 paragraphs of lorum ipsum, each line being a maximum of 78 characters. It begins like this:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean at
iaculis eros. Vivamus consectetur nisl eu turpis ultricies, non ornare ex
bibendum. Aenean egestas tortor nec libero elementum maximus. Curabitur

And on running the script the screen looks like this (I've blocked out a bit of personal information in the shell prompts):

You can see that the vim pane doesn't render starting at the first line, and only half the pane has text, even though the file is much larger. Hitting Ctrl-L doesn't help.
The solution I've found is odd. It's to add a sleep to the first main line of the script, like this:
tmux new-session -d "sleep 1 ; vi lorem.txt" 

When I do this, everything works fine.
So I have two questions:

Why does this kludged solution work?
What is a more elegant solution?

Here are some further things I can say...

tmux is version 3.4, vim is version 9.1, my OS is WSL using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
echo $COLUMNS is 188 outside tmux
echo $COLUMNS is 93 inside tmux (right hand pane)
:echo &columns is 94 inside vim in tmux (left hand pane)
echo $TERM is xterm-256color outside tmux
echo $TERM is tmux-256color inside tmux (right hand pane)
:echo &term is tmux-256color inside vim in tmux (left hand pane)
The problem doesn't occur if I omit the tmux split-window.
The problem still occurs if I change the order of execution, like this:

#!/bin/sh

tmux new-session -d
tmux split-window -h
tmux select-pane -t 0
tmux send-keys "vi lorem.txt" C-m
tmux attach-session

Any help to solve the mystery is appreciated.

What if you swap Vim with some other TUI program?

Good question. I tried it with htop, nano and with emacs -nw instead of vim. They all work fine with it. So that suggests it's vim-specific. But still, why would sleep 1 before vim help it run properly?

The time it takes to attach to a tty?

I don't understand ttys well, and I can only guess what "attach to a tty" means. However, if do the new-session without a shell command, and then send-keys "tty" C-m, then it prints out a tty such as /dev/pts/2. That's without putting in a sleep. So I think this implies there is a tty there from the first instant.

Maybe it is there but Vim takes its sweet time? If you are sure that the problem only happens with Vim, you should open an issue on its issue tracker.

(1) I may open a bug in vim, but that feels like a more significant action than is currently warranted. BTW, I'm not sure this is vim taking its time. The sleep happens before the vim command is executed. It's as if somethine else needs time to happen, which vim depends on.
(2) An update on testing. I tried this with an empty .vimrc and with no vim plugins installed and no .viminfo file. The problem persists even in this setup, so it's nothing about how I've configured vim.
